# How to serialize a Java Map to PHP's array serialization format

Tags: java, arrays, serialization

I want to convert `HashMap` to a `String`, which corresponds to PHP's Array serialization format as described here:

http://php.net/manual/en/function.serialize.php

For example:

```
a:5:{s:5:"width";i:450;s:6:"height";i:352;s:4:"file";s:32:"2018/09/Sawtooth-Oak_450_a-1.jpg";s:5:"sizes";a:9:{s:9:"thumbnail";a:4:{s:4:"file";s:32:"Sawtooth-Oak_450_a-1-150x150.jpg";s:5:"width";i:150;s:6:"height";i:150;s:9:"mime-type";s:10:"image/jpeg";}s:6:"medium";a:4:{s:4:"file";s:32:"Sawtooth-Oak_450_a-1-300x235.jpg";s:5:"width";i:300;s:6:"height";i:235;s:9:"mime-type";s:10:"image/jpeg";}s:32:"twentyseventeen-thumbnail-avatar";a:4:{s:4:"file";s:32:"Sawtooth-Oak_450_a-1-100x100.jpg";s:5:"width";i:100;s:6:"height";i:100;s:9:"mime-type";s:10:"image/jpeg";}s:21:"woocommerce_thumbnail";a:5:{s:4:"file";s:32:"Sawtooth-Oak_450_a-1-250x250.jpg";s:5:"width";i:250;s:6:"height";i:250;s:9:"mime-type";s:10:"image/jpeg";s:9:"uncropped";b:1;}s:18:"woocommerce_single";a:4:{s:4:"file";s:32:"Sawtooth-Oak_450_a-1-350x274.jpg";s:5:"width";i:350;s:6:"height";i:274;s:9:"mime-type";s:10:"image/jpeg";}s:29:"woocommerce_gallery_thumbnail";a:4:{s:4:"file";s:32:"Sawtooth-Oak_450_a-1-100x100.jpg";s:5:"width";i:100;s:6:"height";i:100;s:9:"mime-type";s:10:"image/jpeg";}s:12:"shop_catalog";a:4:{s:4:"file";s:32:"Sawtooth-Oak_450_a-1-250x250.jpg";s:5:"width";i:250;s:6:"height";i:250;s:9:"mime-type";s:10:"image/jpeg";}s:11:"shop_single";a:4:{s:4:"file";s:32:"Sawtooth-Oak_450_a-1-350x274.jpg";s:5:"width";i:350;s:6:"height";i:274;s:9:"mime-type";s:10:"image/jpeg";}s:14:"shop_thumbnail";a:4:{s:4:"file";s:32:"Sawtooth-Oak_450_a-1-100x100.jpg";s:5:"width";i:100;s:6:"height";i:100;s:9:"mime-type";s:10:"image/jpeg";}}s:10:"image_meta";a:12:{s:8:"aperture";s:1:"0";s:6:"credit";s:0:"";s:6:"camera";s:0:"";s:7:"caption";s:0:"";s:17:"created_timestamp";s:1:"0";s:9:"copyright";s:0:"";s:12:"focal_length";s:1:"0";s:3:"iso";s:1:"0";s:13:"shutter_speed";s:1:"0";s:5:"title";s:0:"";s:11:"orientation";s:1:"0";s:8:"keywords";a:0:{}}}
```

I've started with the following test Map:

```
        HashMap images2 = new HashMap();
        images2.put("test1", "t1");

        imagesArray.put("width", image.getWidth());
        imagesArray.put("height", image.getHeight());
        imagesArray.put("file", destinationFile);
        imagesArray.put("sizes", images2);

String jsonResult = mapper.writerWithDefaultPrettyPrinter()
                                .writeValueAsString(imageMap);

                        System.out.println(jsonResult);
```

and the reasult is:

```
    {
  "file" : "/images/bolivia.jpg",
  "sizes" : {
    "test1" : "t1"
  },
  "width" : 450,
  "height" : 450
}
```

Comment: It is not clear what you are trying to do. What are those numbers 5, 450 etc. in `s:5:"width"`, `i:450`, `s:6:"height"`, and what do the letters mean like `i`, `s` (looks like the type of the fields?) ? In your example you are using JSON, which doesn't look like what you want at the top.

Comment: If you copy the String and past it here: https://www.unserialize.com and click "Unserialize" you will get Array. In PHP there is method http://php.net/manual/en/function.serialize.php

Comment: Yes but that is PHP specific, Java doesn't do that. So you can either go through the process of checking the type of each field in your `Map` and outputing it as explained there (so if you find a String you put `s`, if the string is numeric or you have an integer you put `i` etc.) ... or do what the rest of the world does and use standard JSON. You can then just use PHP's `json_decode()` instead. http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php

Answer (score 0):

Java does not use PHP's array serialization format so you have to write it yourself or change approach. You have the following options:

1. Iterate through the entries of your `Map` and for each entry output its type, `s` for `String`, `i` for `int` etc. together with the rest of the information (a `String` includes the length etc.)
2. From your PHP script, change approach and instead of reading PHP's array serialization use JSON. This is more of an open defacto standard, and you will be able to use other programming languages too since most languages support JSON or have easy libraries to do so these days.
3. Use a library which saves Java objects to PHP's serialization format. I would only recommend this option if you have no control on the PHP script and you absolutely cannot change it without breaking something else. If you do not own the PHP code, or you cannot maintain it effectively it may be a viable option. Do a quick search for Java libraries that do this such as this one:

https://github.com/marcospassos/java-php-serializer

Answer (score 0):

Ok, i found solution - i will use

```
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.xk72/pherialize -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.xk72</groupId>
    <artifactId>pherialize</artifactId>
    <version>1.2.4</version>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 0):

Consider using Google's protobufs (prototype buffers). Protobufs are implemented in several languages, including Java, PHP, Python, C++, and so on.

It has the advantage of language independence--you define the buffer structure and compile the definition file into the language(s) of your choice.

Here's a trivial example of a protobuf with 2 fields, just to give an idea:

```
syntax = "proto2";
message CookiejarTransaction {
    optional string action = 1; // Action is either "bake" or "eat"
    optional uint32 amount = 2; // Amount is number of cookies
}
```

Disclaimer: I have no interest in Protobufs other than a happy developer who uses the tool.

https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/